# how to add the keys of an array to the url in file_get_contents?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, file-get-contents

I want to add the keys of the array id
to the end of foobar.com to grab the content but the output is 
error: array to string conversion

```
$digitsL = file_get_contents('digitslist.txt');
preg_match_all('#[0-9]{17}#',$digitsL,$digits);
$url = "http://www.foobar.com/";
foreach($digits as $value){
$newurl = $url.$value;
$daten = file_get_contents($newurl);
}
```

based on the answer of robby, i changed the code to

```
foreach($digits[0] as $value){

$daten[] = file_get_contents($url.$value);
}
```

Comment: `$newurl = ` instead of `$newurl .=`?

Comment: is `httpd` a typo? also, can you show the complete error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), the third parameter to the `preg_match_all` function is a multi-dimensional array. So, `$digits[0]` will contain an array of strings that matched the full pattern.

You would have to do something like this:

```
foreach($digits[0] as $value) {
    $url .= $value;
    // ...
}
```